# Ball and Plate System PSO PID tuning

Tags: pid-controller, particle-swarm

[Ball and Plate Sytem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXuhx.png)
i read some documents about PSO PID tuning and i recognize that they make inner and outer loop but i do not know why and how , i mean where to set PSO algorithm and if i run it while system is running it will cause delay so how can i solve this problem and how can i implement PSO PID tuning for the ball and plate system.

i expect solution for this problem and how can i implement PSO algorithm for the ball and plate system.

Comment: You are mixing concepts. The optimization algorithm goal is to optimize the tuning parameters according to certain control objective, like overall tracking integral $\int\limits_{0}^T r x^2 dt$, for example. Does it make more sense for you?

Comment: i know i use pso to optimize the pid values so i set pid equation as objective function and the set the cost function to be cost_function = M_p + t_s where M_p is peak overshoot and t_s is settling time , my problem should i run the PSO before the system to get the PID values or during the system running

Comment: I will give you a proper answer on post.

Comment: Would you mind posting it on Mathematics Forum, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given a linear system $\ddot{x} + a_1 \dot{x} + a_0 x = u$, we design a PID controller $u = k_2 \int\limits_0^\infinity (x - x_r) dt + k_1 (x - x_r) + k_0 (\dot{x} - \dot{x}_r)$ such that the objective function $J$ given by $\int\limits_0^\infinity (\dot{x} - \dot{x}_r)^2 dt$. We now can use find adequate values for variables $(k_0, k_1, k_2)$ which minimize objective function $J(k_0, k_1, k_2)$. We may even add control boundary constraints, like $\abs{u} < u_r$

Among optimization methods, we may cite Particle swarm optimization method: It consists on a heuristic based on multiple agents evaluated on different points of parameter space. After perform the optimization procedure, we have the (sub-)optimal values for desired control performance.